# CSV import issue with php in MySQL using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a little problem in my job using php to import csv.
I'm currently working on the code of someone else.

He import many csv without problem, but when I use the same algorithm I have some troubles going on.

He's using this function :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$filename.'"
INTO TABLE '.$tablename.'
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED by \';\'
ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
ESCAPED BY \'"\'
LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'
IGNORE 1 LINES'
```

The problem I Have is that the import is acting weird.

This is the list of what I could observe :

- It import only the first row
- The first row is not always ignored, like if there is the name of column in the csv it ignore, if I remore it, it doesn't.
- The format is not the problem, I tried taking one file that work and paste the info in it, then save as.
- The first field in the database is always 0
- The result differ in function of where the columns are in the file : Like if there is A, B, C it can be empty for the two others fields (first one always 0). But if I place it A, C, B or B, C, A or whatever, the fields may be filled.

Thank's for your time and ask me if you need any other information about my code !

Comment: Make sure your file has the correct encoding (utf-8? iso-8859-1? you might need to specifiy the character set during import) and correct line endings (\r\n).

Comment: Thank's for your answer !
How do I check the encoding ?
The line endings is defined in the code below, isn't it enough ?

Comment: Have you checked your MySQL for errors? Regardless if you are using PHP or not , your MySQL server is executing your query , so if anything strange is happening it will have logged it.

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin, the errors are logged in this ? Or where should I check ?

Comment: Yes phpmyadmin reports any sql errors. Regarding encoding: Use google ;-)
I personally use Scite to see if there is a UTF8 BOM at the beginning of the file

Comment: I checked for the report but I can't find anything about it on my version.. It seems like I don't have the access to it.
Regarding encode I tried using file that work and modify them. No change!